# I'm making a rob command and I don't know how to make it activate the timeout when it fails or subtract the coins from the person

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm working on the economy part of my discord bot and while making a rob command it wouldn't subtract the coins from the person robbed but it would still give me coins. I also want it to activate the timeout when you fail to rob someone but it just won't so can someone please help?

**My rob command code:**

````
const ms = require('parse-ms');

module.exports = {
    name: "rob",
    description: "Make an attempt to steal money from another user",

    async run (client, message, args) {
        let user = message.author;
        let userMention = message.mentions.users.first()
        let timeout = 7200000;
        let author = await db.fetch(`worked_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`);
        let userBalance = await db.fetch(`money_${message.guild.id}_${getUserFromMention}`);
        let amount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 1;
        const robChance = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

        if(userMention === undefined) return message.channel.send('Who do you want to rob?')

        if(userMention === user) return message.channel.send('How stupid are you to rob yourself?')

        if(userBalance > amount) return message.channel.send('They are to poor for you to rob.')

        if(robChance === 0 ) return message.channel.send('The cops caught you and you couldn\'t get any money.')

        

        if(author !== null && timeout - (Date.now() - author) > 0){
            let time = ms(timeout - (Date.now() - author));
            return message.channel.send(`The cops are looking for you. You shouldn't try and rob somebody else for another **${time.minutes}m** and **${time.seconds}s**.`)
        } else {
            db.add(`money_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, amount)
            db.subtract(`money_${message.guild.id}_${getUserFromMention}`, amount)
            db.set(`robbed_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, Date.now())

            message.channel.send(`You robbed ${userMention} and got **${amount}** coins`)
        }
    }
}

function getUserFromMention(mention) {
    if (!mention) return;

    if (mention.startsWith('<@') && mention.endsWith('>')) {
        mention = mention.slice(2, -1);

        if (mention.startsWith('!')) {
            mention = mention.slice(1);
        }

        return client.users.cache.get(mention);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Console.log can help

Comment: I dont get any errors in the console though it just doesn't happen.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it. Long ago

Comment: [Cryodream](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16569218) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68606000) saying "You never defined db, make sure to do that"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix:

```js
const ms = require('parse-ms');

module.exports = {
    name: "rob",
    description: "Make an attempt to steal money from another user",

    async run (client, message, args) {
        let user = message.author;
        let userMention = message.mentions.users.first()
        let timeout = 7200000;
        let author = await db.fetch(`worked_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`);
        let userBalance = await db.fetch(`money_${message.guild.id}_${getUserFromMention}`);
        let amount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 1;
        const robChance = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

        if(userMention === undefined) return message.channel.send('Who do you want to rob?')

        if(userMention === user) return message.channel.send('How stupid are you to rob yourself?')

        if(userBalance > amount) return message.channel.send('They are to poor for you to rob.')

        if(robChance === 0 ) return message.channel.send('The cops caught you and you couldn\'t get any money.')

        

        if(author !== null && timeout - (Date.now() - author) > 0){
            let time = ms(timeout - (Date.now() - author));
            return message.channel.send(`The cops are looking for you. You shouldn't try and rob somebody else for another **${time.minutes}m** and **${time.seconds}s**.`)
        } else {
            db.add(`money_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, amount)
            db.subtract(`money_${message.guild.id}_${getUserFromMention}`, amount)
            db.set(`robbed_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, Date.now())

            message.channel.send(`You robbed ${userMention} and got **${amount}** coins`)
        }
    }
}

function getUserFromMention(mention) {
    if (!mention) return;

    if (mention.startsWith('<@') && mention.endsWith('>')) {
        mention = mention.slice(2, -1);

        if (mention.startsWith('!')) {
            mention = mention.slice(1);
        }

        return client.users.cache.get(mention);
    }
}
```